# Importing downloaded libraries using npm doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I always get this error with any library I'm trying to import and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. With this case I'm trying to download an SVG library called react-native-svg.

I installed it using npm install react-native-svg

and when I try to import it, it says it can't "resolve it"

pic below

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSEZa.png)

could yall point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Note especially the bullet in the latter that starts "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Answer (score 0):

I know I just posted this, but if it helps anyone in the future, I installed react-native-web using:

npm install react-native-web

and it solved my issue.